# What if antibiotics existed in the Middle Ages?

Tags: biology, medieval, history, medicine

I wonder what would have happened if antibiotics existed earlier, like in the Middle Ages. What do you think would have changed?

Comment: This is off-topic. We can't answer what-if questions because of their overly subjective nature.

Comment: I think its on topic but just a little overbroad.  Effects on what warfare, economics, government.  Each would be a good question.

Comment: You can easily make your question on-topic by asking about a specific thing that could have changed. From our [help page](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), on-topic questions could be `Effects of events or world elements, including biology, technology and magic, on specific aspects of that world's societies, cultures, and environment`. So you can ask how society or culture would have changed with such an event, but not just "what happens?".

Comment: Don't give up! Just think about your universe a little bit (such as WHEN in the middle ages they were discovered, which antibiotic, etc) and go from there!

Comment: What @Samuel said. *What this question needs is to focus on something specific.* State a year when antibiotics were discovered, and ask how that might affect some specific aspect of the world. That would be answerable. "What would have changed?" given some vaguely described change like "antibiotics discovered in the middle ages" is, unfortunately, too broad, because there are just too many possible answers and each of those would need to go into far more depth than we can reasonably expect people to do. The operative words from the help center article are **specific aspects**.

Answer (score 1):

Worldbuiding is a site dedicated to the problems which writers encounter when they invent their *fictional worlds*, be it for a novel, a game, or whatever. It does not deal with the real world, and it does not help people to come up with ideas in the first place. You are a new member, so I'll try to give an answer anyway.

- Antibiotics have to be mass produced in reasonable quantity at reasonable prices to have a large impact. Are you assuming that pharmaceutical factories exist, or are you assuming that they are not necessary to get antibiotics? For instance, there could be a natural source in a plant.
- Antibiotics alone won't improve healthcare. Will there be a soap supply? Germ theory of disease? Sewage treatment plants?
- Incorrectly applied, antibiotics breed resistant germs. Can the people read the instructions?

For these reasons, I believe that there would be a minor reduction of mortality from sickness, but not enough to bring sweeping changes. The upper classes will benefit most. The random survival of some prince or princess could lead to **sweeping** changes in history, but not to changes in the economy and general quality of life.